# local payment api failed to verify the transaction using php

Tags: php, api, curl, payment

This is the API provided by https://www.cashmaal.com/api I deposited some cash in my cashmaal account and the transaction id I got whenever I try to verify the payment by transaction id it shows me an error

> Error: Error! Transaction Id () is invalid.

```
$web_id="";   // Your Web ID here (you can found this on cashmaal account where you add site) 

if(isset($_POST['CM_TID'])) {

    $CM_TID=$_POST['CM_TID'];   // getting TID with user redirection   
    
    $url="https://www.cashmaal.com/Pay/verify_v2.php?CM_TID=".urlencode($CM_TID)."&web_id=".urlencode($web_id);
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    
    $obj = json_decode($result,true);
    
    if($obj['status'] == 1)
    { // it means payment received....
        
        //response format in JSON
        //Example Response
        /*
           {"status":"1","receiver_account":"8","USD_amount":"1.670","fee_in_USD":"0.000","PKR_amount":"280","fee_in_PKR":"0","USD_amount_with_fee":"1.670","PKR_amount_with_fee":"280","trx_website":"website.com","transaction_id":"2JW9651118P","trx_date":"25-03-2020 9:13:48 PM","order_id":"12345678","addi_info":"Test Payment","sender_details":"Fund Received From 161919","trx_details":"$1.67 Receive against TID: '2JW9651118P'"}
         
         */
        // Verify All things and Confirm user order here
        
        if($obj['USD_amount'] == '2')
        {         
            echo 'we received your payment';
        }
        else
        {
            echo "we didn't received the your mentioned payment ";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error:".$obj['error'];
    }
}
```

Comment: this api is for callback of a transaction, how you are doing the transaction and getting transaction id, please share that bit of code for better understanding,

Comment: There is no more code i am just sending transaction id through a form and trying to verifying whether it is valid or invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a solution of this that this cashmaal api verify the transaction id only if the transaction is done by other cashmaal account